# Run a function on data in a go html/template

Tags: templates, go

I want to add hyphens (`-`) to a string in a go template when someone tries to save it. I'm using some modified code from the go wiki tutorial here: https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

Code:

```
<h1>Editing {{.Title}}</h1>                                                            
<form action="/save/{{.Title}}" method="POST">                                         
  <div><input name="title" type="text" placeholder="title"></div>                      
  <div><textarea name="body" rows="20" cols="80">{{printf "%s" .Body}}</textarea></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Save"></div>                                        
</form>
```

The line with

```
<form action="/save/{{.Title}}" method="POST">
```

is the relevant line. I need to transform `.Title` which might be something like "the quick brown fox" to "the-quick-brown-fox".

As you can see in the code above, you can add a function like `println`, but I'm not sure how I would do this for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `template.FuncMap` to the template and then you can do something like:

```
{{ .Title | title }}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KWy_KRttD_

```
func Sluggify(s string) string {
    return strings.ToLower(s) //for example
}

func main() {
    funcMap := template.FuncMap {
        "title": Sluggify,
    }

    tpl := template.Must(template.New("main").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(`{{define "T"}}Hello {{.Title | title }} Content: {{.Content}}{{end}}`))
    tplVars := map[string]string {
        "Title": "Hello world",
        "Content": "Hi there",
    }
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "T", tplVars)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your *Page structs are created by the loadPage function. So it would seem to be easiest to just create your hyphenated title then and store it in your page struct:

```
type Page struct {
    Title string
    HyphenTitle string
    Body  []byte
}

func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error) {
    filename := title + ".txt"
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Page{Title: title, Body: body, HyphenTitle: hyphenate(title)}, nil
}

func hyphenate (s string) string {
    return strings.Replace(s," ","-",-1)
}
```

Then just use `{{.HyphenTitle}}` where you want it.